# Object doesn't support property or method 'getAll'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, indexeddb

I am trying to implement service workers into my application, which I have managed to do in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not completely in IE. So far I am able to create an object store and add data to it but when I call `getAll()` I get the following error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAll'

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
var docDB = indexedDB.open("docDB", 1); 
        docDB.onsuccess = function(event) {
            var db                      = docDB.result;
            var tx                      = db.transaction("documents", "readwrite");
            var docStore                = tx.objectStore("documents");
            var docStoreRequest         = docStore.getAll();
            docStoreRequest.onsuccess   = function(event) {
                var rowHTML = '';
                $.each( docStoreRequest.result, function( index, value ){
                    var id          = $(this)[0].id;
                });
            };
```

Comment: On which browser do you have the error ? Did you checked https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction/objectStore ?

Comment: Only happens in internet explorer :(

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: Windows Edge, doesn't look like older versions of IE support service workers

Comment: When you write in the console, what is the result of tx.objectStore("documents") ?

Comment: [object IDBObjectStore]: {indexNames: Object, keyPath: "id", name: "documents", transaction: Object}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither IE nor Edge support all of the IndexedDB spec. One of the missing things is getAll. Fortunately, [there is a polyfill you can use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/indexeddb-getall-shim).

Comment: Went round and round in circles and this worked straight away!